# Dropbox Sync API stops downloading files and calling callback methods

Tags: ios, dropbox, dropbox-api

My iOS app should be able to download huge amount of files from internet (that can be FTP, REST servers or any other kind of source, where user can put his files). I implemented download from Dropbox among other possibilities because of a set of advantages. I'm using Sync API to synchronize data with server.

Problem which i faced is following: some users have lets say 11 800 files and folders in their Dropbox folders and app downloads them one-by-one. Everything seems fine until 31-32 percents of files are downloaded, that is about 3 600 - 3 800 files. Then Sync API library stops calling my callbacks (observer methods) and logs messages:

```
[WARNING] ERR: DROPBOX_ERROR_MISCSYSTEM: cfhttpbinding.c:353: CFHTTP Read Error: (NSPOSIXErrorDomain, 2)
[WARNING] ERR: DROPBOX_ERROR_NETWORK: cfhttpbinding.c:353: CFHTTP Read Error: (kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork, -72000)
[WARNING] ERR: DROPBOX_ERROR_NETWORK: cfhttpbinding.c:353: CFHTTP Read Error: (kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork, -72000)
[WARNING] ERR: DROPBOX_ERROR_NETWORK: cfhttpbinding.c:353: CFHTTP Read Error: (kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork, -72000)
```

.... and so on.

What i noticed while debugging it is that memory usage grows to 600 (six hundreds !!!) MB. I'm using ARC, so in theory no memory leaks are possible. Though developer still can keep a lot of strong references, what will prevent memory from being freed. And of course I do not forget about retain cycles.
I run "Allocations" instrument, used xCode built-in Analyser tool but still can't find and fix this issue. There are no obvious problems with memory usage to me.

Here is the code:

```
- (void) syncImages
{
    if([NSThread isMainThread])
    {
        [self performSelectorInBackground:_cmd withObject:nil];
        return;
    }

    DBPath *path = [[DBPath root] childPath:[SettingsManager dropboxImagesPath]];

    DropboxManagerMetadata *metadata = [DropboxManagerMetadata new];
    metadata.totalAmount = &m_uTotalAmountOfImages;
    metadata.currentAmount = &m_uCurrentImage;
    metadata.updateFiles = m_lstImageUpdateFiles;
    metadata.continueBlock = ^(uint uTotalAmount, uint uCurrentAmount)
    {
        BOOL bContinue = !m_bImagesDownloadPaused;
        return bContinue;
    };
    metadata.shouldProcessFileBlock = ^(NSString * const strRemotePath)
    {
        NSArray *lstPathComponents = [strRemotePath pathComponents];
        // at first check if new file is related to images at all
        // if we have path "/items/some_image.jpg, then we'll have the following path components
        // 1. "/"
        // 2. "items"
        // 3. "some_image.jpg"
        NSString *strRemoteFirstPathComponent = [lstPathComponents objectAtIndex:1];
        BOOL bShouldProcess = [strRemoteFirstPathComponent compare:[SettingsManager dropboxImagesPath] options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch] == NSOrderedSame;

        return bShouldProcess;
    };
    metadata.willDownloadFileBlock = ^(NSString * const strRemotePath)
    {
        NSMutableString *strLocalPath = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:strRemotePath];
        [strLocalPath replaceOccurrencesOfString:[SettingsManager dropboxImagesPath]
                                      withString:[SettingsManager appItemsDefaultPath]
                                         options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [strLocalPath length])];
        [strLocalPath setString:[SettingsManager itemPath:strLocalPath inDirectoryOfType:DirectoryTypeCaches]];

        return strLocalPath;
    };
    metadata.fileProcessedBlock = ^(uint uTotalAmount, uint uCurrentAmount, NSString * const strFilePath)
    {
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:cstrNotificationDropboxImagesDownloadProgress object:nil];
    };
    metadata.fileUpdatedBlock = ^(NSString * const strLocalPath)
    {
        NSArray *lstPathComponents = [strLocalPath pathComponents];
        if([lstPathComponents count] < 2) return;

        NSString *strItemNo = [lstPathComponents objectAtIndex:[lstPathComponents count] - 2];
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:cstrNotificationDropboxImageUpdated object:self userInfo:
         [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:strItemNo forKey:cstrNotificationDropboxKeyItemNo]];
    };
    metadata.directoryProcessedBlock = ^(DBPath * const dbPath, NSArray * const lstContents)
    {
        NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
        NSMutableString *strLocalPath = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:[dbPath stringValue]];
        [strLocalPath replaceOccurrencesOfString:[SettingsManager dropboxImagesPath]
                                      withString:[SettingsManager appItemsDefaultPath]
                                         options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [strLocalPath length])];
        [strLocalPath setString:[SettingsManager itemPath:strLocalPath inDirectoryOfType:DirectoryTypeCaches]];

        NSMutableArray *lstLocalContents = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[fileManager contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:strLocalPath error:nil]];
        if(lstLocalContents)
        {
            [lstLocalContents filterUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"NOT (SELF BEGINSWITH[c] %@)", [ItemImagesAccessor previewImagePrefix]]];
            [lstLocalContents filterUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"NOT (SELF IN %@)", lstContents]];
            for(NSString *strFileName in lstLocalContents)
                [self deleteOldImagesAtPath:[strLocalPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:strFileName]];
        }
    };

    [self calculateTotalAmountFilesAtPath:path withMetadata:metadata];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:cstrNotificationDropboxImagesDownloadProgress object:nil];
    [self downloadContentsOfDirectoryAtPath:path withMetadata:metadata];
}

- (void) calculateTotalAmountFilesAtPath:(DBPath * const)dbPath withMetadata:(DropboxManagerMetadata * const)metadata
{
    DBFilesystem *filesystem = [DBFilesystem sharedFilesystem];
    if(!filesystem) return;

    if(!metadata || !dbPath) return;

    NSArray *lstContents = [filesystem listFolder:dbPath error:nil];

    for(DBFileInfo *info in lstContents)
    {
        if(metadata.shouldProcessFileBlock && !metadata.shouldProcessFileBlock([info.path stringValue])) continue;

        if(metadata.totalAmount)
            *(metadata.totalAmount) = *(metadata.totalAmount) + 1;

        if(info.isFolder)
            [self calculateTotalAmountFilesAtPath:info.path withMetadata:metadata];
    }
}

- (void) downloadContentsOfDirectoryAtPath:(DBPath * const)dbPath withMetadata:(DropboxManagerMetadata * const)metadata
{
    DBFilesystem *filesystem = [DBFilesystem sharedFilesystem];
    if(!filesystem) return;

    if(!dbPath || !metadata) return;

    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

    DBError *error = nil;
    NSArray *lstContents = [filesystem listFolder:dbPath error:&error];
    if(error)
        DDLogWarn(@"error while listing contents at path: %@. code: %u, description: %@", dbPath, [error code], [error localizedDescription]);
    DDLogInfo(@"%u items found in directory: %@", [lstContents count], [dbPath stringValue]);

    float fProgress = 0.f;
    NSMutableArray *lstContentsFromDropbox = [NSMutableArray new];
    for(DBFileInfo *info in lstContents)
    {
        if(metadata.continueBlock && !metadata.continueBlock(*(metadata.totalAmount), *(metadata.currentAmount))) break;

        if(metadata.shouldProcessFileBlock && !metadata.shouldProcessFileBlock([info.path stringValue])) continue;

        if(metadata.currentAmount)
        {
            *(metadata.currentAmount) = *(metadata.currentAmount) + 1;
            if(metadata.totalAmount)
            {
                fProgress = (float)*(metadata.currentAmount) / (float)*(metadata.totalAmount) * 100;
                DDLogInfo(@"processing %u item of %u total amount. progress is %.2f%%", *(metadata.currentAmount), *(metadata.totalAmount), fProgress);
            }
        }

        NSString *strLocalPath = nil;
        if(metadata.willDownloadFileBlock)
            strLocalPath = metadata.willDownloadFileBlock([info.path stringValue]);
        else
            strLocalPath = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:[info.path stringValue]];
        [lstContentsFromDropbox addObject:[strLocalPath lastPathComponent]];

        // check if new item is directory and create directory if needed
        if(info.isFolder)
        {
            if(![fileManager fileExistsAtPath:strLocalPath])
                [fileManager createDirectoryAtPath:strLocalPath withIntermediateDirectories:YES attributes:nil error:nil];

            [self downloadContentsOfDirectoryAtPath:info.path withMetadata:metadata];

            continue;
        }

        DDLogInfo(@"going to open file at path: %@", info.path);
        DBFile *file = [filesystem openFile:info.path error:&error];
        if(error)
            DDLogWarn(@"error while opening file at path: %@. code: %u, description: %@", info.path, [error code], [error localizedDescription]);

        // not nil value for status means, that file at server has some changes
        if(file.newerStatus && [fileManager fileExistsAtPath:strLocalPath])
        {
            // will delete all related preview images if given "strLocalPath" is an image, or simply will delete given file otherwise
            [self deleteOldImagesAtPath:strLocalPath];
        }

        if(file.newerStatus && !file.newerStatus.cached)
        {
            DBFile * __weak fileWeak = file;
            [metadata.updateFiles addObject:fileWeak];
            [file addObserver:self block:^()
             {
                 if(fileWeak.newerStatus.cached || !fileWeak.newerStatus)
                 {
                     DBError *err = nil;
                     [fileWeak update:&err];
                     if(err)
                         DDLogWarn(@"error while updating file at path: %@. code: %u, description: %@", fileWeak.info.path, [err code], [err localizedDescription]);

                     NSData *data = [fileWeak readData:&err];
                     if(err)
                         DDLogWarn(@"error while reading file at path: %@. code: %u, description: %@", fileWeak.info.path, [err code], [err localizedDescription]);
                     [fileManager createFileAtPath:strLocalPath contents:data attributes:nil];

                     [fileWeak removeObserver:self];
                     [fileWeak close];

                     [metadata.updateFiles removeObject:fileWeak];

                     if(metadata.fileUpdatedBlock)
                         metadata.fileUpdatedBlock(strLocalPath);

                     @synchronized(self)
                     {
                         if(![metadata.updateFiles count] && metadata.finishProcessBlock && metadata.isSyncFinished)
                             metadata.finishProcessBlock();
                     }
                 }
             }];
        }
        else
        {
            NSData *data = [file readData:&error]; // get the latest data
            if(error)
                DDLogWarn(@"error while reading file at path: %@. code: %u, description: %@", file.info.path, [error code], [error localizedDescription]);
            // and create file at appropriate directory
            [fileManager createFileAtPath:strLocalPath contents:data attributes:nil];

            [file close];
        }

        if(metadata.totalAmount && metadata.currentAmount)
            metadata.fileProcessedBlock(*(metadata.totalAmount), *(metadata.currentAmount), strLocalPath);
    }

    if(metadata.directoryProcessedBlock)
        metadata.directoryProcessedBlock(dbPath, lstContentsFromDropbox);
}
```

Explanation of the code and usage conditions:

1. Methods "calculateTotalAmountOfFilesAtPath: ..." and "downloadContentsOfDirectoryAtPath: ..." are recursive, but recursion never goes deeper than at 1st level (0, 1, 0, exit). example is: /items/1000300/1000300.jpg. "/items/" path is given as initial argument, "1000300/" is level 0, "1000300.jpg" - level 1.
2. Level 1 always contains only 2 - 3 files. For example contents of directory "/items/1000300" would always be something like "1000300.jpg", "1000300a.jpg", "1000300b.jp". Main data set is received at level 0: there are a lot of sub-directories at the initial path. for example, "/items/1000001", "/items/1000002", ........ "/items/1007654".
3. There is local variable "NSMutableArray *lstContentsFromDropbox = [NSMutableArray new];", which keeps paths for contents of particular directory. it may cause problems on level 0 (see point 2), but i tried to excluded it from algorithm - there is no significant improvement.

Can the bug be caused by implementation of Sync API itself? Is there any workaround for it?

Thanks.

P.S. I'm more interested in finding some info about log messages from Dropbox Sync API than about how to debug memory issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was caused by high memory usage (not leaks). App had to perform similar action in a loop, which has more that 11 thousands of iterations. And even if some memory is allocated on a heap, there is still other memory, which is allocated on a stack. Also we should not forget about autoreleased objects, which still exist with ARC.

I solved my problem partially by wrapping loop iterations into @autoreleasepool blocks.
It is the same as with non-arc environment: even if you do not need some object anymore and release all your references to this object, you still don't know when will it be purged from memory if it was autoreleased before.

Anyway i'm going to re-implement this algorithm, because loading 11 thousands objects to memory and keeping them in a list for processing in a loop is not really good idea.